# ReactJS defaultChecked in multiple checkboxes with reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, loops, checkbox, checked, reactstrap

I found out defaultChecked in multiple checkboxes is quite slow to render.

```
let data1 = this.props.data1
let data2 = this.props.data2

let renderData = data1.map((item, index)=>{
    let defaultChecked = false
    if ( data2.length != 0 ) {
        data2.map((cat, x)=>{
            if ( item.id == cat ) {
                defaultChecked = true
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <FormGroup key={index} check>
            <Label check>
                <Input 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
                    value={item.id}
                    onChange={this.props.handler}
                />{' '}{item.name}
            </Label>
        </FormGroup>
    )
})
```

If I change it to `checked` then it's will work. But var defaultChecked not working when I change it to `defaultChecked` in checkbox. I don't understand why it doesn't work, may be I don't understand how `defaultChecked` work.

p/s: I using reactstrap, not material ui

Comment: Are you trying to use `checked`? Can you post the "not working" code?

Comment: Is your problem, slow rendering or checkbox not working?

Comment: @riwu the code above is not working code.

Comment: @GautamNaik Actually is 'late rendering'. I still checking on my code. But if I use `checked`, it's work fine.